# AppleScript issues with Terminal commands

Tags: terminal, applescript

I want to run this command in Terminal via AppleScript but Script Editor doesn't like the dollar sign. It says: Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found unknown token. How can I enter this command into Terminal without Script Editor complaining? I'm totally new to this and this command is not mine, I don't really want to change it.

```
tell application "Terminal"
do script "exec ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)""
end tell
```

Comment: The problem appears to be your double quotes.  Try `do script "exec ruby -e '....`  (Use a single quote to encapsulate everything starting with the $)

Comment: Go ahead and write up an answer and I'll upvote you so you can gain some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems with the quoting of commands in a command.

An easy way out is to put the command ina shellscript e.g. name the script ~/bin/install_homebrew and after creating it make it executable

Script is

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)
```

the call the script from the terminal or from Applescript

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script exec "~/bin/install_homebrew "
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the inner double quotes (") with a backslash (), like so

```
do script "exec ruby -e \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubuser......install)\""
```